# What is the motivation behind Tao's properties of $\epsilon$-closeness? (elementary real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

In Analysis 1 by Terrence Tao, Tao introduces the concept of $\epsilon$-closeness, defined as follows

> Let $\epsilon > 0$ be a rational number, and let $x, y$ be rational numbers. We say that $y$ is $\epsilon$-close to $x$ iff we have $|y - x| \leq \epsilon$.

He then goes on to give the following list of easy to prove properties of epsilon closeness.

> 1. If $x = y$, then $x$ is $\epsilon$-close to $y$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Conversly, if $x$ is $\epsilon$-close to $y$ for every
>      $\epsilon > 0$, then we have $x = y$
> 2. Let $\epsilon > 0$. If $x$ is $\epsilon$-close to $y$, then $y$ is $\epsilon$-close to $x$.
> 3. Let $\epsilon, \delta > 0$. If $x$ is $\epsilon$-close to $y$, and $y$ is $\delta$-close to $z$, then $x$ and $z$ are $(\epsilon +
>     \delta)$-close.
> 4. Let $\epsilon > 0$. If $x$ and $y$ are $\epsilon$-close, they are also $\epsilon'$-close for every $\epsilon' > \epsilon$
> 5. Let $\epsilon > 0$. If $y$ and $z$ are both $\epsilon$-close to $x$, and $w$ is between $y$ and $z$ (i.e. $y \leq w \leq z$ or $z \leq
>     w \leq y$), then $w$ is also $\epsilon$-close to $x$.
> 6. Let $\epsilon > 0$. If $x$ and $y$ are $\epsilon$-close, and $z$ is non-zero, then $xz$ and $yz$ are $\epsilon|z|$-close
> 7. Let $\epsilon, \delta > 0$. If $x$ and $y$ are $\epsilon$-close, and $z$ and $w$ are $\delta$-close, then $xz$ and $yw$ are
>      $(\epsilon|z| + \delta|x| + \epsilon\delta)$ close.

Some of these properties can be easily motivated. $\epsilon$-closeness itself is easily motivated, as it is so essential to the formalization of calculus. 1-3 formalize the concept of $x$ and $y$ being $\epsilon$-close as "almost" equivalent. More precisely, they show that $\epsilon$-closeness is almost like to being an equivalence relation.

4 seems so basic and intuitive as to be worth proving.

However, 5-7 are less intuitive, especially 7.

Other lists of properties so far in this book have had clear motivation. For example, Tao has list of properties that are group, ring, and field axioms for $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z},$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. Tao has properties showing that absolute value $|x - y|$ is a distance function, etc. But I am not aware of any underlying algebraic structure that these last 3 properties could be motivated with.

### Here is my question:

Out of all the properties Tao could have put in this list, how did he know these would be sufficient to build the rest of the book off of? What made him choose these properties?

Comment: Tao uses $\varepsilon$-closeness to construct $\mathbb{R}$ by defining $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as the equivalence class of all Cauchy $\mathbb{Q}$-sequences which should "converge" to $x$. In some sense this is natural and intuitive, although others (e.g., Rudin) develop the Dedekind cut construction instead.

Comment: To build on this, 5 says that being $\epsilon$-close plays nice with the order on $\mathbb{Q}$, 6 and 7 say that being $\epsilon$-close plays nice with the multiplication on $\mathbb{Q}$. When we use the $\epsilon$-close formalism to build $\mathbb{R}$, these results ensure that it will have the same structure as $\mathbb{Q}$, with the addition of a property known as *completeness*.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Thanks! This got me closer to understanding, but I still have questions. Why does 6 alone not not say that being $\epsilon$-close plays nice with multiplication. Why do we need 7 in addition that? 

When you say that these results ensure that it will have the same structure as $\mathbb{Q}$ what exactly does that mean? And how do we know that?

Comment: That, presumably, will be the subject of the text. I don't want to give too much away. In other words, I'm lazy and don't want to reproduce the entire Cauchy sequence construction of the real numbers in a stack exchange post.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Upon thinking about it more, I think I understand. If $\epsilon$-closeness is an "almost" equivalence relation, then it makes sense to prove that if $x$ and $y$ are "almost" equal, and $z$ and $w$ are "almost" equal, then $xz$ and $yw$ are "almost" equal. Property 6 is really just a special case property 7, so I am now thinking it is just there as a stepping stone to help with the exercise of proving these properties.

Comment: That's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

Probably from
$(x-a)(y-b)
=xy-xb-ya+ab
$
so
$|xy-(x-a)(y-b)|
\le |xb|+|ya|+|ab|
$.